# Access resolve function outside of a JavaScript Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an object that needs to have a single point of initialization, and other callers need to wait until the initialization is complete before continuing.

I have done this with jQuery, and it feels like I'm working with the design, but the same approach with a native JavaScript Promise seems like it is going against the grain.

I need to replace use of jQuery promise with a native JS Promise.

**Is this initialization pattern OK, or is there a better approach?**

*On the surface it seems that an event pub/sub pattern would be a better fit, but I can't guarantee that the `init()` will be called before the `ready()` is called, which would result in missed events.*

**jQuery**

```
function Foo() {

    var dfd= $.Deferred();
    this.ready = function () {
        return dfd.promise();
    }
    this.init = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            dfd.resolve();
        }, 2000);
    }
};

var foo = new Foo();

//foo.ready() may be called from multiple places.
foo.ready().then(function () {
    alert('foo.ready');
});

//foo.init would only be called once.
foo.init();
```

**JavaScript Promise**

```
function Foo() {

    var resolver,
        rejector,
        readyPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolver = resolve;
            rejector = reject;
        });

    this.ready = function () {
        return readyPromise;
    }
    this.init = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolver();
        }, 2000);
    }
};

var foo = new Foo();

//foo.ready() may be called from multiple places.
foo.ready().then(function () {
    alert('foo.ready');
});

//foo.init would only be called once.
foo.init();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your question runs on these assumptions:

- You want to hook up multiple listeners to a single Promise.
- The promise is triggered arbitrarily, not necessarily on promise creation.
- You want to use native promises.
- You run on an engine that has Promises.

The second bullet point, where the operation is triggered arbitrarily, is the tricky part because native promises are read-only. You'll need to catch `resolve` and `reject` from the constructor every time.

So while your implementation is correct, you'll find yourself repeating the pattern. jQuery `Deferred`s are better in this case, but we don't want to lug around jQuery, or any library for that matter.

What you could do is create your own little `Deferred` constructor. It just wraps around the existing native `Promise` API, essentially just forwarding arguments. The only difference is that it's exposing `resolve` and `reject`.

```
function Deferred(callback){
  var instance = this;

  // Catch the resolve and reject
  this._resolver = null;
  this._rejector = null;
  this._promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    instance._resolver = resolve;
    instance._rejector = reject;
  });

  // Deferred has { resolve, reject }. But personally, I like the Promise
  // version of resolve and reject as separate args.
  if(typeof callback === 'function')
    callback.call(this, this._resolver, this._rejector);
}

Deferred.prototype.then = function(resolve, reject){
  return this._promise.then(resolve, reject);
};

// resolve, reject etc.

// For other APIs, refer to jQuery for Deferred and MDN for Promises:
// https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
```

Now with Deferred out of the way, let's go back to your jQuery version and improve it. Since we created `Deferred` as a constructor, we can *subclass* from it. This means we can have `Foo` become a `Deferred` and have the luxury of the `Deferred` API.

```
// Setup Foo as a Deferred in as little as 2 lines.
function Foo(){ Deferred.apply(this, arguments); }
Foo.prototype = Object.create(Deferred.prototype);

// Your Foo API
Foo.prototype.init = function(){
  var instance = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
    instance.resolve();
  }, 2000);
};
```

In the end, `foo` will have `Deferred` powers, care of an extended `Promise` API.

```
var foo = new Foo();

// We can now use `then`.
foo.then(function(){
  alert('foo.ready!');
});

//
foo.init();
```

Now if I wrote the code properly, this should work:

```js
function Deferred(callback) {
  var instance = this;
  this._resolver = null;
  this._rejector = null;
  this._promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    instance._resolver = resolve;
    instance._rejector = reject;
  });
  if (typeof callback === 'function')
    callback.call(this, this._resolver, this._rejector);
}

Deferred.prototype.then = function(resolve, reject) { return this._promise.then(resolve, reject); };
Deferred.prototype.resolve = function(resolution) { this._resolver.call(null, resolution); return this; };
Deferred.prototype.reject = function(rejection) { this._rejector.call(null, rejection); return this; };

// The setup code:

function Foo() { Deferred.apply(this, arguments); }
Foo.prototype = Object.create(Deferred.prototype);

Foo.prototype.init = function() {
  var instance = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    instance.resolve('YAY!');
  }, 2000);
};

// Phew! Now your Foo is a "native" Deferred.

var foo = new Foo();

foo.then(function(value) {
  alert('foo.ready! ' + value);
});

foo.init();
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying the implementation.  Can you provide any thoughts on whether events would be more suitable, given the note at end of my question?

Comment: @JosephGabriel Your observation regarding events is correct. There ambiguity when an event has already fired, and a handler is attached *after* it. Events can also fire more than once, making it more confusing. Events are for messaging, fire and forget, and don't keep state. Promises, however, do keep resolution/rejection which makes it good in your init scenario.